# How to convert Image to byte-array?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, base64, tint

I am using the base64 image in HTML to render the images in PDFViews. In some cases, I have to change the color of the png/svg images dynamically. So, I want to know *how to change the tint color of the image and convert that image to base64*?

**How to change that image icon to base64 string, which we will render in pdf using HTML.**

```
Image mImage = Image.asset(
  "assets/images/ic_planet.png",
  color: Color(int.parse("999999")),
); //How to do after this?
```

Comment: Uh ... 1) Decode the base64 text 2) use a library to read the binary image and adjust the color, 3) Resave the binary file, 4) Re-encode saved image file back to base64 test

Comment: Yeah, how to achieve this? I am beginners to flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Converts the Image object into a byte array.

The format argument specifies the format in which the bytes will be returned.

[Official Doc.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html)

```
Future<ByteData> toByteData({ImageByteFormat format = ImageByteFormat.rawRgba}) {
  return _futurize((_Callback<ByteData> callback) {
    return _toByteData(format.index, (Uint8List encoded) {
      callback(encoded?.buffer?.asByteData());
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  RaisedButton(
 onPressed: () async {
 List<int> imageBytes = await sampleImage.readAsBytes();
 base64Image =  base64Encode(imageBytes);
 print(base64Image);},), SizedBox(height: 30,),
 Image.memory(base64Decode(base64Image)),
```

when you apply your file as a readAsBytes then you will get imagesBytes and then after you can easily convert into the base64Encode.

Comment: if any doubt then explain here?

Comment: The method 'readAsBytes' isn't defined for the class 'Image'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'readAsBytes'.dart(undefined_method)

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.